# Replace All within a Regex Search

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm not really good with Regular expression, but I'm trying to run a "Replace All" on a conditional regular expression search.

In my regex search (results(.*)continue), I'm trying to find the word "continue" on lines that also have the word "results". Is there any to replace "continue" of *just* these search results other than manually changing them?

example:

```
Results(.*)Continue
This sentence contains the word continue.
Results 2(.*)Continue
```

to

```
Results(.*)End
This sentence contains the word continue.
Results 2(.*)End
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the most efficient, but try the following:

- Find what: `(?<=Results)(.+)Continue`
- Replace with: `\1End`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

Comment: This is great! Sorry to ask for additional help, but is there any way to refine the original search? Would it be possible to search for lines that contain: results, continue; and excludes: testing

Comment: If this question has been successfully answered, mark it as answered. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). You will need to ask another question and link it to this one as you are including new requirements

Comment: Oh okay, I will try that. Thank you again, Reddy.